# Persistent Volume required in one of the Gitlab CICD pipeline

Tags: gitlab, persistent-volumes

I have a requirement where customer wants to put some java based dependencies in the persistent volume and their app containers can refer that and we have to create cicd pipelines for this use case.

We are using Gitlab for CI and codestream for CD. How it can be possible in this case with regard to persistent volume ? Please suggest

Thanks,

Persistent Volume needs to be created at codestream level and we can refern in gitlab OR something we can deal at Gitlab itself.